# Reusing Space in a react SPA

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this app i am making in react for learning purposes.

[image]

I am using react router and navigating to specific pages isn't a problem. The problem is reusing space when i want to. For instance, to the right when i click charts, i want all content to the left to go and only display a component having my charts.

When i click analysis, i want to show analysis component as its appearing.

How can i replace a component from a section of the page in react without having to load a new page entirely?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can conditionally render left sidebar and main content. Way to do it is by checking `path` from react router. If `path` includes certain string - render some ui, if it doesn't render something else.